# Is it possible to create a program for a "Perfect" Conversion of (JGP, PNG) to SVG Format?

Tags: c++, svg, bitmap

I want to attempt to do the conversions on jpg/pngs to svgs that look at least almost identical to the original image. I have found very little in terms of the ability to convert jpg/png to svg, but I have found many svg to jpg/png converters. What I have found makes the output look cartoonish. Below on the left is a jpg and on the right is a "converted" svg file from that jpg.

This is an example from http://vectormagic.com/
[image]

Based on this lack of information I assume it's a difficult task.

But from a programming standpoint, why is it so difficult to "perfectly" convert a bitmap to a vector?

What challenges are posed?

I understand I need to convert the bitmap to a vector, but is there anything in particular that could be done to overcome this distorted output?

Also which programming language would best if I were to try such a task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG is about *shapes*, not pixels.
To recreate eg. the grass in your picture, with its countless nuances of green, you basically need to find borders of shapes with the same color inside.

This is the problem here: There are no clean uniform-colored shapes like squares etc. in the grass. Either you accept a lower quality (making large parts the same kind of green, instead of recreating the original grass), or you need many shapes of 1x1 size: that are pixels again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. In general, a vector graphics format which includes primitives to draw lines, circles, etc. could also include images which are represented as the sequence of pixel values.

Note that when you write "Perfect conversion" you are meaning pixel by pixel. Then, the question is ¿does svg format include a image pixel a pixel as a primitive? SVG is a great and very complete format.

If you want a very simple example which includes conversion from jpg to svg, take a look to this library:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/libboard/

It is a c++ library which is very simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add that by making each pixel into a SVG primitive, you have created the most inefficient representation of your bitmap image imaginable. The SVG file will be huge!